Old anime with a robot-like creature who had to absorb the male main character to use most of its abilities
So there's this one old anime I vaguely remember watching. Most of the details are lost, but I remember there was this one robot-like creature who had to absorb the male main character to use most of its abilities to fight the enemies they faced. There was also a female main character who moved in with his family. He had a deceased brother, I believe, as well.

In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, was it a movie or a series? And do you recall the hair colour of the male or female MCs?

Sounds very much like FLCL, with the exception that the brother in this isn't dead, he just moved abroad to the US.

Synopsis
Naota Nandaba is an ordinary sixth grader living in a city where nothing amazing ever seems to happen. After his brother Tasuku leaves town to play baseball in America, Naota takes it upon himself to look after everything Tasuku left behind—from his top bunk bed to his ex-girlfriend Mamimi Samejima, who hasn't stopped clinging to Naota since Tasuku left.


Little does Naota know, however, that his mundane existence is on the verge of being changed forever: enter Haruko Haruhara, a Vespa-riding, bass guitar-wielding, pink-haired psychopath whose first encounter with Naota leaves him with tire tracks on his back and a giant horn on his head. Though all he wants is some peace and quiet, when Haruko takes up residence at his parents' home, Naota finds himself dragged into the heart of the greatest battle for supremacy that Earth—and quite possibly the entire universe—has ever seen.

The Main character does get eaten multiple times by a robot to inrease its powers.

An understandable confusion, if so. Some say that moving to the USA is a fate worse than death.

On the contrary, the brother having gone to America is depicted as a sort of apotheosis by the anime; he's simply too cool to exist in Naota's crappy little town.

Could be Reideen?
Akira, the boy who operated Reideen had to jump off his motorcycle to merge into the robot in order to control it. As I recall, he would shout "fado een" (fade in) while he was somersaulting off the motorcycle.
Wiki says

Akira is aided by Mari Sakurano, who happens to be the daughter of a prominent scientist, and his friends from the soccer club.

I don't remember a brother, deceased or otherwise, but I haven't seen the show for almost fifty years.

Perhaps Neon Genesis Evangelion fits the bill? The reboot film series just ended a few years ago, but the original aired in Japan in 1995-96, so it technically predates Google (though not as old as, say, Kimagure Orange Road or Astro Boy).
It fits the gist of your description, although there are some minor(?) differences that make it kind of a stretch:


robot-like creature who had to absorb the male main character to use most of its abilities

The main character, Shinji, is inserted, not absorbed, into the robot-like creature Unit 01, via a cylindrical plug. He's one of the few people on Earth at the time able to pilot it at all, and it's often most powerful when he loses control; for example, he gets knocked unconscious during his first sortie, and Unit 01 goes berserk and annihilates the enemy.

 He does get fully absorbed at one point, however, and Unit 01 literally tears apart and eats the enemy Angel.



There was also a female main character who moved in with his family. He had a deceased brother

He first moves in with one female character, Misato, but another (Asuka) later moves in with them both. And they do act somewhat like a family, or at least siblings (Misato typically acts more like a big sister or "cool aunt" than a mother figure).
His real family almost doesn't factor in; Shinji's father is present, and a major character, but wants little to do with him outside the business of piloting. And he has no brothers, but his mother died while helping to develop the Evangelions.

 In fact, Shinji personally kills the character most like a brother to him, and (at least in the original series) comes close to killing another.

